# How can i call AsyncTask from my adapter class passing String values?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

textview and button in my listview by using adapter class. When i click on  that button i have to call AsyncTask passing parameters i.e String  of that perticular position in adapter class getview method .Here am created my Asynctask is another class i.e an activity class. Please provide some examples.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some code you work with

Comment: @Sajmon.. sorry for that and it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AsycnTask` takes an `Array` of some sort - `Strings` for instance, so when you instantiate the `AsyncTask`, you just pass it an `Array` like so:

```
String[] arr = new String[] {"A string to pass..."};
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.execute(arr);
```

Full example on how to use it:

http://www.android-ever.com/2012/10/android-asynctask-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Create public class in different file or within your activity. If you are creating within Activity then define like this way

```
public class static MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
}
```

and then used anywhere like this

```
YourActivity.MyAsync myAsync = new YourActivity.MyAsync();
```

for passing the value to the your Async class use this way

```
myAsync.execute(yourstring);
```

access in doInBackground like this way

```
public String doInBackground(String... param){
    String s = param[0]; // here you can access  you string like this way
}
```